# Cannot understand what the following code does

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem

Can somebody explain to me what the below code is doing.  `before` and `after` are hashes.

```
def differences(before, after)
    before.diff(after).keys.sort.inject([]) do |diffs, k|
        diff = { :attribute => k, :before => before[k], :after => after[k] }
        diffs << diff; diffs
    end
end
```

It is from the papertrail differ gem.

Comment: The use of `inject` there is somewhat complicated. For a good blog post that starts with the basics of `inject` and builds up to examples like the one you have here, check out this: http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html.

Comment: The use of `inject` here is arguably semantically wrong, and Ruby 1.9 adds [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) which makes more sense for this example.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: No need for `inject` nor `each_with_object`, this should be a `map`, a plain and simple `map`.

Comment: @tokland Ahhh you're right! I thought they were generating a hash, not an array, and spoke too quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's dense code, no question. So, as you say `before` and `after` are hash(-like?) objects that are handed into the method as parameters. Calling `before.diff(after)` returns another hash, which then immediately has `.keys` called on it. That returns all the keys in the hash that `diff` returned. The keys are returned as an array, which is then immediately sorted.

Then we get to the most complex/dense bit. Using `inject` on that sorted array of keys, the method builds up an array (called `diffs` inside the `inject` block) which will be the return value of the `inject` method.

That array is made up of records of differences. Each record is a hash - built up by taking one key from the sorted array of keys from the `before.diff(after)` return value. These hashes store the attribute that's being diffed, what it looked like in the before hash and what it looks like in the after hash.

So, in a nutshell, the method gets a bunch of differences between two hashes and collects them up in an array of hashes. That array of hashes is the final return value of the method.

**Note**: `inject` can be, and often is, much, much simpler than this. Usually it's used to simply reduce a collection of values to one result, by applying one operation over and over again and storing the results in an accumlator. You may know `inject` as `reduce` from other languages; `reduce` is an alias for `inject` in Ruby. Here's a much simpler example of `inject`:

```
[1,2,3,4].inject(0) do |sum, number|
  sum + number
end
# => 10
```

0 is the accumulator - the initial value. In the pair `|sum, number|`, `sum` will be the accumulator and `number` will be each number in the array, one after the other. What `inject` does is add 1 to 0, store the result in `sum` for the next round, add 2 to `sum`, store the result in `sum` again and so on. The single final value of the accumulator `sum` will be the return value. Here 10. The added complexity in your example is that the accumulator is different in kind from the values inside the block. That's less common, but not bad or unidiomatic. (**Edit**: Andrew Marshall makes the good point that maybe it is bad. See his comment on the original question. And @tokland points out that the `inject` here is just a very over-complex alternative for map. It *is* bad.) See the article I linked to in the comments to your question for more examples of `inject`.

**Edit**: As @tokland points out in a few comments, the code seems to need just a straightforward `map`. It would read much easier then.

```
def differences(before, after)
  before.diff(after).keys.sort.map do |k|
    { :attribute => k, :before => before[k], :after => after[k] }
  end
end
```

I was too focused on explaining what the code was doing. I didn't even think of how to simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

It finds the entries in before and after that differ according to the underlying objects, then builds up a list of those differences in a more convenient format.

`before.diff(after)` finds the entries that differ.

`keys.sort` gives you the keys (of the map of differences) in sorted order

`inject([])` is like `map`, but starts with diffs initialized to an empty array.

The block creates a `diff` line (a hash) for each of these differences, and then appends it to `diffs`.

Comment: `inject`, aka `reduce`, is pretty different from `map`. They go together in thought insofar as they work on collections, as do `select`, `each`, `partition` and more, but what they actually *do* is very different. `map` applies some block of code to every item in an array and returns an array of the results. Example: [1,2,3,4].map {|x| x * x}` returns `[1,4,9,16]`. `inject` applies one operation to each item in an array and returns a single result. Example `[1,2,3,4].inject(:+)` applies addition to those numbers and returns `10`.

Comment: @Telemachus: Kevin is right, the snippet does a `inject([])` followed by a `acc << something`. That's a plain and simple `map`, the original author shouldn't have used `inject`.

Comment: @tokland I take your point that the code should use a map, and I updated my answer to include that. However, Kevin's comment is still misleading. Initially, I took him to mean that inject was like map period. That's what I started out trying to respond to. But I think it's misleading even after re-reading the whole comment: "`inject([])` is like `map`, but starts with `diffs` initialized to an empty array." The "but" seems out of place since `map` itself starts with an empty array.

Comment: I said map because I think it's the most commonly understood internal iterator. I guess inject is closest to just `each` with a temp variable initialized first. You're right that the return value makes it very different from map.